# Odata filter query in PowerShell for Dynamics 365

Tags: powershell, odata, microsoft-dynamics

Trying to use a filter on a oData query for D365 F&O data entity however can't seem to get it to work. I get results without filter however what i'm trying to do is use a EQ operator to filter based on a string value. I've tried double quotes, single quotes but none seem to work. Below is the specific line from my PowerShell script.

```
Get-D365ODataEntityData -EntityName SecurityUserRoleAssociations-Token $token -ODataQuery '$filter=UserID eq "ABC"'
```

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/d365collaborative/d365fo.integrations/blob/development/docs/Get-D365ODataEntityData.md) `-ODataQuery` should be `'$filter=UserID eq ''ABC'''`

```
Get-D365ODataEntityData -EntityName SecurityUserRoleAssociations-Token $token -ODataQuery '$filter=UserID eq ''ABC'''
```

Comment: Tried that too but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to user2250152's answer about escaping single quotes, the filter is case sensitive and should be UserId.